# How can I schedule a GBQ query and have the data export to an Excel file every day?

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks, export-to-excel

Fairly new to GBQ as a whole, but I'm familiar with how to schedule a query as well as how to export data to a file, however, I can't for the life of me determine how to schedule the export after the query runs.

Actually, just being able to schedule an export would work perfectly for my needs. Has anybody been able to accomplish this?

Comment: Scheduling an export job is not possible at the moment. What do you have until the moment? Do you have a query scheduled in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags) to orchestrate the query and the load.